# Jquery adding dropdown dynamically and removing it when unchecked

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form below where when a user selects a sport, it is dynamically added. I have implemented code where if a sport is already there, it can not be added again. What I cant figure out is if a user unchecks a sport, I want it removed from the list and the array to and the user is able to add it again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Item listing</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="test.htm" method="get">
    <select name="mylist" id="myList">
      <option id="1">Baseball</option>
      <option id="2">Soccer</option>
      <option id="3">Basketball</option>
      <option id="4">Volleyball</option>
      <option id="5">Hockey</option>
      <option id="6">Football</option>
      <option id="7">Rugby</option>
      </select>
  <br />
  <div id="sList">
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //add item when selected
    //a sport can not be added twice
    var allVals = [];
    $('#myList').change(function () {
        if ($.inArray(this.value, allVals) == -1) {
            allVals.push($(this).val());
            document.getElementById("sList").innerHTML += "<input checked =\"checked\" id=\"wList\" name=\"wList[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" + this.value + "\">" + this.value + "<br />";
        }
    });

    //remove sport when unchecked
    $('#wList').change(function () {
       //???
    });

    //submit should send checked sports

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See [DOM Removal](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-removal/)

Comment: @Cyborgx37, what did you want him to see there?

Comment: @gdoron Several functions for removing an element from the DOM.

Comment: Also see [What Have You Tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Is it possible to access the dynamically added checkbox? A simple test didn't return anything: 

` $('#wList').change(function () {
        alert("test");
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you might remove items from the list. Note that I've made several changes to your code... I've changed the checkbox ID to class--IDs must be unique. I've added labels around your checkboxes to make them more accessible and to make the labels clickable. I've removed the 
 tags after the inputs. Use CSS instead for easier formatting and to simplify the necessary jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/j6G2Y/

```
//add item when selected
//a sport can not be added twice
var allVals = [];
$('#myList').change(function () {
  if ($.inArray(this.value, allVals) == -1) {
    allVals.push($(this).val());
    document.getElementById("sList").innerHTML += "<label class=\"wList\"><input checked =\"checked\" class=\"wList-chk\" name=\"wList[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" + this.value + "\"> " + this.value + "</label>";
  }
});

//remove sport when unchecked
$(document).on("change", ".wList-chk", function () {
  if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
    return;
  } else {
    $(this).parent('.wList').remove();
  }
});

//submit should send checked sports
```

You should be able to remove the item from your array with something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/j6G2Y/1/

```
//remove sport when unchecked
$(document).on("change", ".wList-chk", function () {
  if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
    return;
  } else {
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    var index= $.inArray(thisVal, allVals);

    allVals.splice(index,1); alert(allVals);

    $(this).parent('.wList').remove();
  }
});
```

I've left some alerts in place to monitor the array.

Comment: Nice work. The only thing is that IE is now acting up. The value field is not showing up in IE 8 and the items get added up multiple times.http://oi48.tinypic.com/33atqwh.jpg

Comment: Fixed by swapping **this.value** for **$(this).val()**. Anyone care explaining the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/j6G2Y/5/